# Select item from website dropdown at random - puppeteer, nodeJS

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I want to implement the feature to select from a dropdown menu on a website but I can't seem to be able to find the correct selector to query such that it selects a random item from the dropdown.

example of the dropdown I want to randomly select from

https://www.slamjam.com/en_GB/man/footwear/sneakers/low/nike-running/air-tailwind-79-sneakers/J166713.html

I can get it to click on the dropdown and bring the in-stock sizes but I can't get it to automate choosing a random item from the dropdown list.

In the past, I've been able to select from a Google Forms dropdown and a regular website that had basic dropdowns where I could choose the selector and the value with ease - but on this website, it doesn't seem that straight forward.

I want it to be able to just choose a random option from the dropdown if there are any available.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I haven't been able to navigate the dropdown at all. I can click the dropdown to show the available sizes with await page.click('#select2-select-prenotation-container')

Answer (score 0):

This code will select the first item that is not selected:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('#select2-select-prenotation-container');
await page.click('#select2-select-prenotation-container');
await page.waitForSelector('.select2-results__option[aria-selected="false"]');
await page.click('.select2-results__option[aria-selected="false"]');
```

Keep in mind that there are many disabled items on that list.